# Change font-size in echo table

Tags: php, html, html-table, echo, font-size

I want to modify the font size based on a echo table.
Here you can see me code...

```
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($pdo -> query($abgÜbersicht) as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Spiel']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

I think I have to fill in something like

```
<font-size: "xy">
```

But I am not really sure how to write it correctly regarding to the correct quote signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `style` HTML property.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($pdo -> query($abgÜbersicht) as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style=\"font-size: xy;\">".$row['Spiel']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways inline style and with style tag or separate file. 
Lets first do it in the first way:

```
echo "<table>";
    foreach($pdo -> query($abgÜbersicht) as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "**<font size='16px' color='magenta' family='monospace'>**<td>".$row['Spiel']."</td>**</font>**";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

the second way is to put style tag and give class to td.

```
      echo "<table>";
            foreach($pdo -> query($abgÜbersicht) as $row){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td **class='edit'**>".$row['Spiel']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
             ?>
            <style type='text/css'>
              .edit{ color:magenta; font-size:16px; /*and whatever you 
              want*/
               </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line `how to write it correctly regarding to the correct quote signs.` i would like to share something about quotes in php . it was prepared few month back but while i fail to post . Most of new developer will not know where to use `single quotes` and `double quotes` and how it `behave` .

**1 :** First of all you need to know the difference bewtween single quotes and double quotes and when it's used

**Single quotes**

**2 :** Inside the single quotes everything consider as string .

```
$message1 = '<div style="color:#ff0000"> Message 1 </div>';
```

**2.1 :** Above example you can use double quotes inside single quotes  but you should not use single quotes inside single quotes . if you need to use you need to escape it properly using backward `slash (\)` .
    like this `$message1 = '<div style=\'color:#ff0000\'> Message 1 </div>';`

**Double quotes**

**3 :** Inside the double quotes we can use single quotes `$message1 = "<div style='color:#ff0000'> Message 1 </div>;` but should not use double quotes inside the double quotes .if you need you need to ecape it properly like this 
    like this `$message1 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 1 </div>";`

**4 :**  `$message1 = '<div style="color:#ff0000">$error</div>';`

**4.1 :** In above example $error will consider as string . it will not echo the value of variable ,because it's inside the single quotes .

**overcome :**

you can concatenate like this

```
$message1 = '<div style="color:#ff0000">'.$error.'</div>';
```

**5 :** `$message1 = "<div style="color:#ff0000">$error</div>";`

**5.1 :** In above example $error will consider as variable because it's inside the dobule quotes .

**6 :** `$message1 = "<div style="color:#ff0000">'$error'</div>";`

**6.1 :** In above example $error consider as variable and also it give the value with enclosed by single quotes .